# Re installation of bluedevil or any substitute for it

Tags: bluetooth

I have Kubuntu 14.04 but I've uninstalled Bluedevil with deals with bluetooth. And now I am  not able to use bluetooth. When I try to re install it gives the following note "The "bluedevil" package could not be marked for installation or upgrade: Depends: bluedevil, but it is not installable" via Muon Package Manager. SO how to reinstall it or any other substitute for it.Outcome of "sudo apt-get install bluedevil" as follows
sudo apt-get install bluedevil
[sudo] password for mahesh: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bluedevil : Depends: obex-data-server but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Please paste the output of command: `sudo apt-get install bluedevil`

Comment: @Naveen Please read question again. I've posted output of given command as asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As asked Naveen issued the command. Read the output carefully which tells me that "obex-data-server" is not installed. Then I simply issued command "sudo apt-get install obex-data-server". After installed Bluedevil by "sudo apt-get install bluedevil". And my problem is solved.

Comment: So you read the output and fixed it on your own? Nice :)

Comment: Thanx Naveen for concern.