# Still not able to install 32-packages on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies, android-studio

I have tried several solutions that I found on this forum, but I still haven't been able to install the 32-bit packages that I need for Android Studio. I get the following errors:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    lib32bz2-1.0 : PreDepends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.9-18) but it is not going to be installed
>    lib32ncurses5 : Depends: lib32tinfo5 (= 5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
>                    Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
>    lib32z1 : Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I tried most of the suggestions described in here and several other places already - [How to run 32-bit app in Ubuntu 64-bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit)

I am looking for answers that might not have been captured in that article.

Comment: Did you try the installation instructions at https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html?

Comment: Do one thing read the error from BOTTOM to TOP and go on installing library in that sequence i.e. from BOTTOM to TOP because that how I solved my problem in following link http://askubuntu.com/questions/468085/re-installation-of-bluedevil-or-any-substitute-for-it/468378#468378