# Dependency is not satisfiable

Tags: debian

I'm trying to install rstudio under Kali Linux (64 bit version), but I get a dependency error:

```
gdebi rstudio-1.0.44-amd64.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done  
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: libgstreamer0.10-0
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Hi read the linked question. It is not related to your problem but can give you a way to think  http://askubuntu.com/questions/468085/re-installation-of-bluedevil-or-any-substitute-for-it#

Answer (score 0):

Install the following dependencies and try installing r studio again

1. https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libgstreamer0.10-0/download
2. https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0/download

Then install r-studio like before.
This works for me.